# Mat Datepicker and Ngx-Bootstrap datepicker both not working Mat Dialog control

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular8

I want to have a datepicker in a mat-dialog I am using. But on click the calender is not opening using both ngx-Bootstrap Datepicker and Angular Material Datepicker.

Both these controls are working fine on other component which are not used as Dialog. Is there some other setting which needs to be done so that they work

[image]

```
 <input                 
                 type="text" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Expense Date" class="form-control">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>


                <input type="text"
                placeholder="Datepicker"
                class="form-control"
                bsDatepicker>
```

Expense Date and Datepicker are the two controls I have been trying with. Both not working.

In the screenshot on the main page I have used the same two component and there the controls are working as expected.

Comment: is there any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

Add matInput after type="text"

<input type="text" **matInput** [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Expense Date" class="form-control">